# Can I compare a SELECT output with an integer in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, function, select, subquery

Some time a go I tried to run an Oracle sql query that looked something like this

```
...
OR
(SELECT COUNT(fieldname)
 FROM MYTABLE
 WHERE -- SOME LOGIC HERE --
                             ) > 0
OR
(SELECT COUNT...) = 1
AND
(SELECT COUNT)...) = 5
```

When I selected only the code inside the parenthesis and executed it, it was showing 56 as unique result. But when selecting all the expression, it was reporting an error, on the last line, that has the `>` operator.

Oracle is a new thing for me and I can't install it to test it, but I think it happens because Oracle doesn't let you compare a table with an integer, even if it has just one row. Using a scalar function would solve it? How would this function be implemented? Would I need to extract a value from a single cell?

Just as note, What I actually had is a `CASE` clause with `OR` and `AND` associated to counting `SELECT`'s and comparison with numbers as you see above.

Thanks.

Comment: [Oracle subqueries](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/subqueries.php)

Comment: @Nitish Thank you for the reference, but I still didn't figure out why it's not  comparing the cell content (56) with 0.

Comment: It is not clear what the desired result is. Of course, what you wrote is not a query at all, it is an algebraic inequality (a Boolean expression, with its value not attached or assigned to anything). Do you want a query that will return the string `'True'` if true and `'False'` if false? The number 1 if true and the number 0 if false? Or what else? (Note that Oracle SQL does not support the Boolean data type, so that is not an option). Aleksej's second solution is very much along these lines.

Comment: Yes, I need to use `OR` and `AND` inside `WHEN` concerning a quantity of certain `SELECT` outputs, as I explained editing my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't check the result of a query that way.
If you want to check the result of a `count` againts some value, you can use a PLSQL block:

```
declare
    vCount number;
begin
    select count(*)
    into vCount
    from yourTable
    where ...;
    --
    if vCount > 0 then
        ... 
    end if;
end;
```

... or a simple query like this:

```
select case
        when (select count(*) from yourTable where ...) > 0
            then 'More than 0'
            else '0'
       end
from dual
```

Comment: In the first case, can I manage to create such a PLSQL, using several variables for count results and later using comparisons inside if, inside a `CASE` clause? Because I'm dealing with a really bad code and I need to fix it, without writing all from scratch.

Comment: And in the second case, why does it let me  to make the the comparison between a subquery and a number, only because it's attached to when?

Comment: 1st part: you can declare all the variables you need and use them in different queries; when all these variables will have a value, you'll be able to build whatever logic you need. 2nd part: Oracle SQL does not support the Boolean type, so you can not have a query that returns a Boolean; but  it can handle Boolean logic, so you can use it  in constructs like CASE. Think of a function like `REGEXP_LIKE`: it gives a Boolean result and you can do things like `where regexp_like (...)`, but you can not do `select regexp_like(...)` because this would need to return a Boolean from a SQL query

Answer (score 0):

Without context it's a bit difficult to give you a definitive answer. Perhaps  `-- SOME LOGIC HERE --` represents a correlated sub-query in which case this would do you:

```
select *
from another_table
where exists
    (SELECT null
     FROM MYTABLE
     WHERE -- SOME LOGIC HERE --
                                 )
```

The `count(*)` in the subquery is unnecessary. You're just checking for the presence of at least one record in the subquery's result set, so you don't need to know many there are.

Comment: you are right, I edited my question. Knowing if there's at least one result isn't enough, since other comparisons use `=` and a speciific integer quantity